# How far down the runway does the plane take off?

Tags: calculus, integration

An airplane goes from $0$ to $220$ mph on a runway to take off. Assuming constant acceleration, how far down the runway does the plane travel before take-off?

So I know I have to integrate until I get the distance formula which is $s(t)= \frac{1}{2}at^2 + C$. Since I am not given a time, how do I solve for this? Thank you!

Comment: Use the speed formula, $v(t) = v_0+at $

Comment: If the plane starts from the end of the runway, $C=0$.  You are missing one piece of data, either the acceleration or the time.  Without that, you can't solve the problem.

Comment: @kaharas:  we are given $v_0=0$, but neither $a$ nor $t$.

Comment: Hmm this is all my professor has given us so I was also confused how to do this without another piece of information. Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah, I think the best you can do is $at=220$ and therefore $\frac{1}{2}at^2 = 110t = \frac{220^2}{2a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided data you can't find a single solution, you'll have to deal with a parametric one. This is what you can do:

$s(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2$

$\dot{s}(t) = at$

From these 2, we can get the time:

$220 = at \Rightarrow t = \frac{220}{a}$

so, the solution is

$s(\frac{220}{a}) = \frac{220^2}{2a} = \frac{24200}{a}$

Comment: Thank you, that makes the most sense with the information given. :)